# Having trouble dynamically allocating an array with a created class in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I've actually managed to successfully do a dynamically allocated array with a normal data type, but it was a while ago (like, six chapters!) And I can't figure out why I can't set the array dynamically here - I know it's giving me an int error, but I can't use the class type because the class type doesn't deal with numbers like that. At this point I'm pretty confused. Here's my code including headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "milTime.h"
#include "Time.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
milTime *theta;
bool amOrPm;
int milHr, milSc,milM,times;


cout<<"How many times would you like to convert?";
cin>>times;
theta = new milTime;
*theta = times;
```

And here's my error:

> Error 1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'milTime
>   *'    c:\users\heather\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\military time\military time\source.cpp   17  1   Military Time

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm completely done except for that. Me and my bright ideas to let it be dynamically allocated!

Here's the milTime class that was requested:

```
#ifndef MILTIME
#define MILTIME

#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"

class milTime : public Time
{
protected:
int milHours;
int milMins;
int milSeconds;
public:
void setTime(int h)
{
    milHours = h;
}
void setMin(int m)
{
    milMins=m;
}
void setSec(int s)
{
    milSeconds=s;
}
int getmilHours()
{return milHours;}

int getmilMins()
{return milMins;}

int getmilSeconds()
{return milSeconds;} 


bool timeConverter(int mTime, int mMins, int mSecs)
{
    bool aOrPm;
    min = mMins;
    if(mTime<12)
    {
        hour = mTime;
        aOrPm = false;
        //AM will be false.
    }
    else if (mTime>12 && mTime<=24)
    {
        hour = mTime%12+1;
        aOrPm = true;
    }
    sec = mSecs;
    return aOrPm;
}
};
#endif
```

Comment: At which line do you _think_ you are dynamically allocating an array?

Comment: `(*theta)` have type `milTime` and `times` have type `int`. So, `(*theta) = times` is `milTime obj = int`

Comment: You are not dynamically allocating an array anywhere. In any case, prefer `std::vector<milTime>` over a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: Given the resent update this: `*theta=times` seems very dangerous. It might wright the value into milHours. Did you forget the [] or to use a vector as already suggested?

Comment: Forgot the [] - I knew there was something I was missing and the textbook is terrible on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are already answers why your code doesn't work
just in case you wanted to allocate an array of milTime, you will need to do it like this:

```
theta = new milTime[times];
```

this will create `times` of `milTime` objects

anyway, you should be using `std::vector` instead of dynamic allocations, this is much safer

Comment: You just answered a different question :)

Comment: I'll have to read on vectors over the summer, we spent literally like five minutes on them in class.

Comment: @Rasmus that's because OP was talking about dynamically allocating an array

Comment: I know, and it even appeared that he was actually trying to dynamic allocate and not just confused terminology.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to dynamically allocate an array of milTime, sorry if I wasn't clear enough about that.

Answer (score 1):

What is the definition of `milTime`?

You are trying to assign an `int`, which is an inbuilt integer type, into your own type milTime. Which won't work unless your type has an assignment operator which takes an `int`.

Does your type have a constructor that takes an `int`? as in that case you would want something more like:

`theta = new milTime(times);`

Answer (score 0):

`theta` is a pointer to `miltime` but `times` is an `int` hence `*theta = times;` fails.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
*theta = times;
```

theta is a class of milTime, times is an int.

You'll probably need to create a setter method in milTime, like this:

```
theta.setTime( times )
```

I can't see your milTime class though, can you post it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that in this line:

```
*theta = times;
```

You try to assign an int to a `milTime`. 
you can fix this by either doing a `static cast`:

```
*theta = static_cast<milTime>(times);
```

Or oldschool cast:

```
*theta = (milTime) times;
```

But prefarbly you can add a constructor to `milTime` (in miltime.h):

```
milTime(int i) : someInnerDataWhichIsAnInt(i) {}
```

The last one is preferable as casts are a sign of a bad structure.
To use the last one do this:

```
theta = new milTime(times);
```

Or is it because you need an array? Prefaably use:

```
std::vector<milTimes> theta() // You need to remove prior definition of `theta`.
```